# AttributeError: 'CommandQueue' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I am trying to calculate a FFT with pyFFT. But the following code results in the error.

```
self.ctx = cl.create_some_context(interactive=False)            
self.queue = cl.CommandQueue(self.ctx)   
self.plan = Plan(fft_size, self.queue)   
gpu_data0 = cl_array.to_device(self.ctx, self.queue, ref_input)
```

ref_input is of type:

```
< type 'numpy.ndarray' >
```

debug output:

```
< pyopencl._cl.CommandQueue object at 0x7f0686c10628 >    
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__enter__', '__eq__', 
 '__exit__','__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', 
 '__instance_size__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', 
 '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', 
 '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_get_cl_version', 'context', 'device', 
 'finish', 'flush', 'from_int_ptr', 'get_info', 'int_ptr', 'properties',    
 'reference_count']   

Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "../dsp.py", line 200, in gpu_fft
     gpu_data0 = cl_array.to_device(self.ctx, self.queue, ref_data)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyopencl/array.py", line 1446, in to_device
     if ary.dtype == object:
 AttributeError: 'CommandQueue' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

In fact I cannot find 'dtype'. But why?

Comment: what is ref_input? a numpy object?

Comment: its of type `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: `pdb` is your friend. or would you like us to debug it for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function pyopencl.array.to_device does not take the context as a parameter according to the documentation.  Use this instead:

```
gpu_data0 = cl_array.to_device(self.queue, ref_input)
```